# Trouble Retrieving Proper Results with Laravel Eloquent Relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I'm having trouble retrieving a certain set of results with my Eloquent relations.

**Models:**
Application(table: application) [**id**, title, active]
Question(table: question) [**id**, *application_id*, question_text, helper_text, **question_type**]
QuestionType(table: question_type) [**id**, type]
Bold = primary key, italic = foreign key

**Relationships:**
One `Application` has many `Questions`.
Many `Questions` can belong to one `Application`.

One `Question` has one `QuestionType` (referenced by question_type FK)
One `QuestionType` can belong to many `Questions` (by referencing it's id as a question_type)

`QuestionType` is a static table that will never have values added or removed, however the type attributes can change.

I would like to be able do something like this:

```
$application = Application:find($application_id);  
$questions = $application->questions()->get();
```

and have that replace `question_type` with the appropriate type pulled from the `QuestionType` model.

I have look through the Laravel and Eloquent docs, asked on IRC, and looked through other StackOverflow articles, yet could not find an answer that helped. I think what is throwing me off is my unconventional foreign key, `question_type`, in my `Question` table. I got it to KIND OF work once, exception `question_type` was being replaced with an `QuestionType` array (which won't work).

Comment: Can you call your field `question_type_id` instead? That might eliminate some confusion and make things work a little more naturally.

Comment: I could, but the thing is I need that question_type for other purposes (mostly working with decision logic). Would it be possible to just tack the "type" onto the Question results instead of replacing question_type with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id say first add this relationship to `Question`:

```
public function type(){
   return $this->belongsTo('QuestionType', 'question_type');
}
```

Then just use it like normal:

```
$question = Question::find(1);
$question->type;
```

And for all questions of an application (with eager loading)

```
$application = Application:find($application_id);  
$questions = $application->questions()->with('type')->get();
```

### Edit

To get only the actual name of the type (column named `type`) you can add an [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators). However with that the naming gets a bit more difficult. If you really don't want to change your foreign key name to `question_type_id` I suggest this:

```
public function typeRelation(){
    return $this->belongsTo('QuestionType', 'question_type');
}

public function getTypeAttribute(){
    if(is_null($this->typeRelation)) return null;
    return $this->typeRelation->type;
}
```

The attribute accessor allows you to use `$question->type` and get the attribute of the related model directly. Don't forget to adjust the relation name when eager loading: `with('typeRelation')`

Comment: I like this, it eliminates the naming conflict between property and relationship.

Comment: Yes. Also, in my opinion, having `$question->questionType` is quite redundant. I like `$question->type` a lot more :)

Comment: Ah, that's a lot closer! Now it returns this (by iterating through the collection): {"id":2,"type":"Short Answer","created_at":"2015-01-26 20:33:29","updated_at":"2015-01-26 20:33:29"}

Is there a way I can access it like $q->type and just receive "Short Answer"?

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Or do you only want the actual name? (`type`)

Comment: It's much closer, turns out I can do $q->type->type and get "Short Answer". Is that the final result of the relation, or can I get it so just $q->type returns short answer?

Comment: Perfect. You just saved me many additional hours of head->desk with both the original and edited answers. Thank you!

Comment: Add a check for `null` in the accessor. It might not be necessary in this very case (I suppose a question cannot exist without a type) but it's a good practice to save yourself a headache one day, when you loop through the `questions` and there's one without related model.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Good catch. I added it to the answer

Comment: @MikeRinehart Make sure to check out the updated answer with a nullcheck in the accessor to prevent future headaches ;)

Comment: Good addition, Jarek. Thanks, both of you!